# Stack around variable corrupt, not sure what the problem is

Tags: c++, variables, stack

**Problem solved, thank you all for the help**

I've got a bit of a problem here it's not something that's blowing my program up, but it's just bothering me that I can't fix it.  I have a function reading in some data from a file, at the end of the execution, the stack around variable longGarbage is corrupted.  I've looked around a bit and found that a possible cause is writing to invalid memory.  I cleaned up some memory leaks that I had and the problem still persists.  What's confusing me is that it happens when the function finishes executing, so it appears to be happening when the variable goes out of scope.  Here's the code...

```
CHCF::CHCF(std::string fileName)
: PAKID("HVST84838672")
{
FILE * archive = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "rb");
std::string strGarbage = "";
unsigned int intGarbage = 0;
unsigned long longGarbage = 0;
unsigned char * data = 0;
char charGarbage = '0';

if (!archive)
{
    fclose (archive);
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    fread(&charGarbage, 1, 1, archive);
    strGarbage += charGarbage;
}


if (strGarbage != PAKID)
{
    fclose(archive);
    throw "Incorrect archive format";
}
strGarbage = "";

fread(&_gameID, sizeof(_gameID),1,archive);
fread(&_fileCount, sizeof(_fileCount),1,archive);

for (int i = 0; i < _fileCount; i++)
{
    fread(&longGarbage, 8,1,archive); //file offset

    fread(&intGarbage, 4, 1, archive);//fileName

    for (int i = 0; i < intGarbage; i++)
    {
        fread(&charGarbage, 1, 1, archive);
        strGarbage += charGarbage;
    }

    fread(&longGarbage, 8, 1, archive); //fileSize

    fread(&intGarbage, 4, 1, archive); //fileType

    data = new unsigned char[longGarbage];

    for (long i = 0; i < longGarbage; i++)
    {
        fread(&charGarbage, 1, 1, archive);
        data[i] = charGarbage;
    }

    switch ((FILETYPES)intGarbage)
    {
    case MAP:
        _maps.append(strGarbage, new CFileData(strGarbage, FILETYPES::MAP, data, longGarbage));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    delete [] data;
    data = 0;
    strGarbage.clear();
    longGarbage = 0;

}
fclose(archive);
} //error happens here
```

Here is the CFileData constructor:

```
CFileData::CFileData(std::string fileName, FILETYPES type, unsigned char *data, long fileSize)
{
_fileName = fileName;
_type = type;
_data = new unsigned char[fileSize];

for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    _data[i] = data[i];
}
```

Comment: <s>What's `fread()`</s>? Woops, I mis `read`.

Comment: @muntoo: Likely the C standard library function `fread`.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned long)` probably isn't 8 bytes.  What compiler/platform/architecture are you using?

Comment: Also, don't throw strings or other literals.  Please use an exception class.

Comment: VC++ 2008.  However, the program writing the file is VC# 2010.  The BinaryWriter class in .NET appears to be automatically writing the long as 8 bytes.

Comment: A C# long is an int64 which is indeed eight bytes long.  But a C++ long is (usually) not eight bytes long and a Visual C++ 2008 long is definitely not eight bytes long.  If the file was written with an eight byte integer then you should be reading into a `unsigned long long` or an `unsigned _int64`

Comment: Better yet, if possible use the managed version of C++ and then you can use the BinaryReader to consume your file.

Comment: @Frank: or better yet, don't rewrite anything, and just insert compile-time assertions to validate that the integer type has the right number of bytes!

Comment: @André I see what you're saying, and now that the code is written perhaps re-writing it is more effort but using BinaryReader to consume the output of BinaryWriter seems easier to me - and probably less effort to support in the long term

Comment: Who downvoted this long after I got my answer and why? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that something is writing to memory around or over the location of longGarbage which is causing the corruption.

You don't say what development environment you are using.  One way to diagnose this would be to set a breakpoint that triggers when a specific memory location changes.  Choose a memory location that overlaps the area of corruption and wait for it to trigger unexpectedly.

Another way to diagnose this would be to examine code that changes memory around or over longGarbage.  That could be almost anything of course but likely candidates are modifications to 'data', modifications to 'intGarbage' and modifications to 'longGarbage' itself.

We can narrow things down even further because we can (usually) be fairly sure the assignment operator itself is safe.  Code like `data = new...` isn't likely to be the culprit so really we need to focus on memory changes that involve taking the address of 'data', 'intGarbage' or 'longGarbage'.  In particular memory changes that change more bytes than they should.

Several others have already pointed out that a long is probably not eight bytes in length.  If you pass the wrong length to fread, the extra bytes retrieved have to go somewhere.

Comment: Where would those extra bytes be going? Reason I ask is because the value of longGarbage is correct each time it's read.  Regardless, I'm going to be working with the file format to get the length corrected.

Comment: They'll go to the next higher memory location.  Remember Windows on Intel is little-endian.  The four least significant bytes of the value retrieved will go into longGarbage, the next four bytes retrieved will go into whatever's next to longGarbage - in this case intGarbage (in a Release build anyway, debug builds have extra bytes in between to help catch this type of bug).  If the original value written by BinaryWrites is small enough to fit in four bytes, the extra four bytes will be zero.

Comment: Ahh I understand now.  So the reason I'm getting the correct values is because the written value is small enough to fit in the 4 bytes.

Comment: That's correct.  That and the fact that you happen to fread longGarbage before you fread intGarbage.  If you had read them the other way round the first read would have filled intGarbage and then the read of longGarbage would have zeroed out intGarbage.

Comment: Well, I changed the longGarbage to type __int64 and it seems to have remedied the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Might I suggest `std::vector` instead of calling new and delete manually? Your code is not exception safe -- you leak if an exception is thrown.
2. `fread(&longGarbage, 8, 1, archive); //fileSize` Are you sure `sizeof(long)` is 8? I suspect it's 4. I believe on Linux boxes sometimes it's 8, but most everywhere else `sizeof(long)` is 4, and `sizeof(long long)` is 8.
3. What about any constructors on members of this class? They can corrupt the stack too.

Comment: 1. That might be a more suitable alternative to manage leaks.
2. Yes, I tested it out several times and the data coming in is correct each time.

EDIT: You seem to be correct on the long size!  I'll make this change in the program and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @MGZero: Yes -- RAII makes leaks a thing of the past. `auto_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, and `unique_ptr` for single pointers, `vector` for arrays.

Comment: Huh, well it certainly isn't happy with using 4 for the sizeof.  I'll have to check the program that's writing this file and see what the deal is over there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of magic numbers for data sizes, so I would check that first.  In particular, I doubt that `sizeof(unsigned long)==8` and `sizeof(unsigned in)==4` in all possible circumstances.  Refer to your compiler's documentation, but you should still be wary, as this is very likely to change from one compiler/platform to another.

Check for these bits:

```
fread(&longGarbage, 8,1,archive); //file offset
```

You also might want to use C++ `<iostream>` library instead of the C `FILE*` stuff for reading.  It would allow for a much shorter version because you wouldn't need to close the file 3 times.

Comment: Thank you, looking into this now on the program actually writing the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the other comments and the information provided that the issue is on the C++ side you should use either __int64 for a windows environment, or int64_t for cross platform.